# Global Layout and positionning

Tags: css

I'm beginning the integration of a design.

- The first navbar is always there.
- Sometimes i have my second navbar.
- The content is never under the navbars
- These 2 navbars have to be on the top of the header.
- These 2 navbars have to be "infinite" to the bottom of the page.
- The body hasn't a fixed width.

[image: first layout possible] 
[image: second layout possible]

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <nav id="main-nav">main-nav</nav>
    <nav id="sub-nav">sub-nav optionnal</nav>
    <section id="main-section">main section</section>
</body>
```

I tried to put the 2 nav bloc as absolute, but my content section is not dynamicly on their left. [[fiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/uuqk8dd4/3/)

```
header { height: 250px; }
#main-nav {
  width:150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
}
#main-section { margin-left:150px; }
```

I tried float left but my nav is not over the header.

Do you have some ideas? I can use bootstrap 3 even if the design has not to be responsive

Comment: you want nav to go to top of the header?

Comment: yes, the nav should be a bit over the header

Comment: why don't you just move the nav tag before header?

Comment: I just tried and it seems to me that i'll still have to dynamicly change the left margin of my content section when i have my subnav, if i want to keep the header under the navs. I'm a beginner I don't see anything obvious

Comment: you know I didn't completely get what you want to achive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJzReW

```
header { 
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;  
}
#main-nav, #sub-nav {
  width:150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#main-nav {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 500px;
}
#sub-nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height:  450px;
}
#main-section { 
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

With `position: relative;` the element's original space is kept (in this case, we use it for maintaining the width), but you can move them (in this case, using a negative margin top).

## Edit

In case you want the navs to touch the bottom of the page, I think this approach can be better: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwgJEQ?editors=110

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header { 
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
#main-nav, #sub-nav {
  width:150px;
  position: absolute;
}
#main-nav {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 100px;
}
#sub-nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  bottom: 0px;
}  
#main-section { 
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
  padding-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: It looks good, thanks a lot! Do you know how can we have a height of 100% for the 2 navs ?

Comment: That was my first approach, but the content is "hacked" with the margin left: When I have ony the first nav the content shouldn't have the margin. Thanks a lot for your help anyway

Comment: There is no margin left! What I'm using is `padding-left: 300px;`. If you only have the first nav, change that to `padding-left: 150px;`